# Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:jar'

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to add a library to kotlin-web-demo. Unforunately I am getting this error:

```
$ ./gradlew ::copyKotlinLibs ; ./gradlew war

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':versions:1.3.31:library'.
> Could not resolve com.github.komputing.kethereum:model:0.75.1.
  Required by:
      project :versions:1.3.31
   > Could not resolve com.github.komputing.kethereum:model:0.75.1.
      > Could not parse POM https://jitpack.io/com/github/komputing/kethereum/model/0.75.1/model-0.75.1.pom
         > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:jar'
> Could not resolve com.github.komputing.kethereum:erc55:0.75.1.
  Required by:
      project :versions:1.3.31
   > Could not resolve com.github.komputing.kethereum:erc55:0.75.1.
      > Could not parse POM https://jitpack.io/com/github/komputing/kethereum/erc55/0.75.1/erc55-0.75.1.pom
         > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:jar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

This is the change I made and how I understood the README:

```
diff --git a/versions/1.3.31/build.gradle b/versions/1.3.31/build.gradle
index 1e0ab00e..721c12e0 100644
--- a/versions/1.3.31/build.gradle
+++ b/versions/1.3.31/build.gradle
@@ -40,6 +40,8 @@ repositories {
     maven {
         url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev"
     }
+    jcenter()
+    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
 }

 configurations {
@@ -106,7 +108,8 @@ dependencies {
      *      permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
      * };
      */
-
+    library "com.github.komputing.kethereum:model:0.75.1"
+    library "com.github.komputing.kethereum:erc55:0.75.1"
     compile fileTree(dir: projectDir.toString() + File.separator + "kotlin", include: '*.jar')
 }
```